# JSON schema equivalent of XML schema keyref

Tags: json, foreign-keys, jsonschema

I am trying to create a JSON schema for data that looks like this:

```
{
  "equipments": {
    "A": {},
    "B": {}
  },
  "work": [
    {
      "equipment": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

The schema I currently have is this:

```
{
  "$id": "example",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "equipments":{
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": true
    },
    "work": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "equipment": {
            "type": "string",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the equipments object different pieces of equipment are configured. These should then be referenced from items in the work array. In an XML schema I would do this with a keyref but I cannot find any equivalent for JSON schemas. Is there an equivalent or is this just not possible with JSON schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible to validate relational data in JSON Schema.

There is a JSON Schema Vocabulary created to [reference instance data](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-vocabularies#accessing-instance-and-external-data), but I don't think that would do what you're looking for either.

There was an effort to define a Vocabulary for [databases](https://github.com/json-schema-org/vocab-database/blob/main/database.md), but that has stalled.