# How can I define JSON reference relationships in XML Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have been trying to search for this answer and have come up empty. I'm starting to believe that JSON Schema does not address this need.

When working with XML Schema it is possible to define relationships in the instance document with key & keyref. There does not seem to be an equivalent for JSON schema.

In the following example JSON Schema, I would like to be able to specify that the "key" property in things is a unique key that can be referenced and that the "keyRef" property of "stuff" is referencing a things item by "key". The same as I could accomplish with XML Schema and 'Key' and 'KeyRef' attributes.

```json
{
  "things": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {"type": "string","format": "uuid"},
        "more": {}
      },
      "additionalProperties": true
    }
  },
  "stuff": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "keyRef": {"type": "string", "format": "uuid"}
      },
      "additionalProperties": true
    }
  }
}
```

Some use cases include:

- additional JSON Schema validation that includes validation of references
- code generation that understands these reference relationships, and
- serialization/deserialization that can leverage these relationships for referential integrity.

Comment: Maybe this can help or set you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261378/json-schema-equivalent-of-xml-schema-keyref